# Use PHP + jQuery when click on a button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a button on my page :

```
<button class="play"></button>
```

When I click on it, it launches the video via jQuery

```
$('.play').on('click',function(){
    player.play();
});
```

But I also want to add PHP code to save the user ID in the database when he clicks on that button.

How can I mix PHP & jQuery? I'm not used to Ajax, is it the solution?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: RTM http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: At a high level, yes you would use AJAX for this.  You'd create some kind of server-side handler which accepts the user ID as an input (form POST, query string value, it doesn't much matter) and stores it as needed.  Then you'd use the jQuery AJAX (`.ajax()`, `.get()`, `.post()`, whichever is easiest for you) to make a request to that server-side handler, sending it the value from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ajax

```
 $('.play').on('click',function(){
    player.play();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "some.php",  // your php file name
      data:{id :"id"}, //pass your user id
     success:function(data)
    {
   if(data==true)
    alert("success");
else
  alert("error");
    }
    });
    }
```

### some.php

```
<?php
$success=false;  //Declare and initialize a variable 

// do your code to update your database
//and check if the database is updated , if so set $success=true

echo $success;


?>
```

Comment: You should check and see if there were any errors.  If there was a php error `success` would still be displayed even though that is not entirely true.

Answer (score 2):

add a function:

```
function add_to_db(user_id){
    $.post('add.php', {userId: user_id}, function(response){
        //do something with the response
        r = JSON.parse(response);
        if (r.status === 'error'){
        //handle the error
        alert(r.message);
        }
    });
});
```

when you play do the following

```
$('.play').on('click',function(){
    player.play();
    user_id = //however you chose to set this in the page
    add_to_db(user_id);
});
```

your add.php:

```
//perform your db update or insert
//if successful:
$response['status'] = 'success';
//else:
$response['status'] = 'error';
$response['message'] = 'update was not successful';
//look into try/catch blocks for more detailed error messaging.

//then send the response back
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: You are missing a `'` after `error` in the first block of code.

Comment: No problem.  I do it all the time ;)

Comment: No need for `r = JSON.parse(response);`. You can do it automatically by appending `"json"` after the success callback

Comment: @Eagle. Really? so function(response, JSON)?

Comment: @SmithSmithy, in fact in this case it should be `$.post(url,data,callback,"json");` Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @Eagle, ok now i understand.. Thanks for the tip